# IF statement not working in a simple login programme

Tags: java, if-statement, authentication

Hello I am writing a simple login programme in Java and I am having issues as even when the correct account number and password is entered I still get the 'Please enter the correct Account number/ Password' and I cannot seem to see where the error is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Main2 extends JFrame{

        public static int x=0;

        public JPanel panel;
        String accountnumber = "123456";
        JTextField inputUser;
        String password = "admin";  
        JPasswordField inputPass;  

        public JLabel lblctr;

        public Main2(){ 
            setTitle("Login");
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(500, 450, 500, 500);
            panel = new JPanel();
            setContentPane(panel);
            panel.setLayout(null);

            inputUser = new JTextField();
            inputUser.setBounds(130, 30,125, 20);
            panel.add(inputUser);
            inputUser.setColumns(10);

            inputPass = new JPasswordField();
            inputPass.setBounds(130, 60, 125, 20);
            panel.add(inputPass);
            inputPass.setColumns(10);

            lblctr = new JLabel("Attempts:");
            lblctr.setBounds(80, 135, 72, 17);
            panel.add(lblctr);

            JButton cancelbtn = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
});

            JButton loginbtn = new JButton("Login");

            loginbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){

                    if((inputUser.getText().equals(accountnumber)) && (inputPass.getPassword().equals(password))){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Press OK to Continue!","Login success!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else{
                        x++;
                        if(x>3){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Too many attempts","Access Denied!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please input correct Account Number/Password","Login Failed!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                    lblctr.setText("Attempts : "+x);
                }});

            cancelbtn.setBounds(170,105, 89, 21);
            panel.add(cancelbtn);

            loginbtn.setBounds(50,105, 89, 21);
            panel.add(loginbtn);

            JLabel lbluser = new JLabel("Account Number:");
            lbluser.setBounds(12, 34, 100, 10);
            panel.add(lbluser);

            JLabel lblpass = new JLabel("Password:");
            lblpass.setBounds(50, 62, 72, 17);
            panel.add(lblpass);
        }

        public static void main (String[]args){
            Main2 proj = new Main2();
            proj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            proj.setVisible(true);
            proj.setSize(320,190);
            proj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
}
```

Comment: `inputPass.getPassword().equals("password")` must be the reason.. Remove double quotes

Comment: @user7: almost. If he did this, he'll be directly comparing a String with a `char[]` for equality, which is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I agree with you...

Comment: @user7: and I with you. :)

Comment: User removed the content of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JPasswordField#getPassword()` returns a char array, not a String, and so comparing "password" and inputPass.getPassword() directly is bound to fail. Use the Arrays method to compare char arrays, not the `equals(...)` method.

Also, user7 is correct, you're trying to use the password variable name as a String which will also fail. Get rid of the quotes.

e.g.,

```
if (Arrays.equals(password.toCharArray(), inputPass.getPassword()))
```

Other issues:

- **Never** have this in your code: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. The code is deprecated for a very good reason and should not be used. Instead go to the API to see why the code is deprecated and use the alternatives that the API suggests.
- You should avoid use of null layout and `setBounds(...)` as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Instead use the layout managers to help you create good looking, functional and easily maintained GUI's.

Comment: so in my case      `if (Arrays.equals(password.toCharArray(), inputPass.getPassword()) && Arrays.equals(accountnumber.toCharArray(), inputUser.getText()) ){`

Comment: @DinoArmadillo: the proof is in the testing. What happens when you do this?

Comment: ++ for `Arrays.equals(password.toCharArray(), inputPass.getPassword())` instead of `new String(inputPass.getPassword()).equals(password))`. `getPassword` returns `char[]` so we could remove content of this array when it is processed to not let it lie in memory until garbage collector kicks in, which could give other (unwanted) process time to read this data from memory and know sensitive data.

Comment: Yeah if `(Arrays.equals(password.toCharArray(), inputPass.getPassword()))` works but I need both Account Number and Password to be validated and when I try to link them both up with a simple && `if (Arrays.equals(password.toCharArray(), inputPass.getPassword()) && (Arrays.equals(accountnumber.toCharArray(), inputUser.getText()) )` equals

Comment: @DinoArmadillo Your code should look more or less like http://pastebin.com/Fb66BM2j

Comment: It worked!, big thanks to you man that helped me out alot